# Проблема в скрипте bash (запуск из крона)

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, cron

```
export PGPASSWORD=foo             
export PGUSER=bar     
today=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")
echo "Делаю дамп продуктовой базы в папку dump"
pg_dump -h db-postgresql-baz-user.db.ondigitalocean.com \
-p 25060 defaultdb > dump/dump_$today
echo "Дамп сделан с именем" dump_$today
today_minus_5_days=$(date --date="5 days ago" +"%Y_%m_%d")
echo "Дамп с именем" $today_minus_5_days "будет удалён"
rm dump/$today_minus_5_days
```

Данный скрипт предназначен для создания дампов бд.
Скрипт отлично выполняется, когда я запускаю его так:

```
./dump.sh
```

но не хочет работать, когда запускается из крона:

```
* * * * * /root/strikecom/dump.sh 1>>/root/strikecom/log.txt
```

Точнее, он запускается, и в лог пишутся сообщения из echo, но файл дампа не создаётся. Помогите

Comment: Поменять  это на что то более портабельное "dump/dump_$today.", тогда не будете зависит от  того где скприпт запускается, думаю он просто жалуется что нету "dump"  директории.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в том, что крон запускает скрипт, находясь в домашней папке пользователя. Изменил команду

```
/root/strikecom/dump.sh
```

на

```
cd /root/strikecom && ./dump.sh
```

Comment: Крон как раз запускает НЕ в домашней папке

Comment: Если вы собираетесь выполнять скрипты не из консоли - делайте полные пути до директорий и файлов, или прописывайте в скрипте все нужные переходы.